# The business of making banners, posters, flyers, etc

Tags: word-request

There's this company making banners, flyers, handouts, and billboard posters down the street where I live. What are such companies called in English? I can say this has something to do with advertising but I'm not sure how the business must be addressed.

Comment: A **printer** makes those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are usually called **print shops.** Services can vary widely, but most small shops offer offset printing and digital printing of brochures, flyers, business cards, signs/banners, and office reports. Some shops can print magazines, books, T-shirts, and promotional items.

A print shop may have only one or a few clients, or it could provide short-run services to any customer who walks in off the street. The latter is sometimes called a **copy shop**. Kinko's is an example of one such chain. Copy shops are similar to print shops, except are less focused on high-end professional printing and more focused on offering resources that a customer would normally find in an office. For example, there are usually a number of copy machines, fax machines, and personal computers available, and sometimes even meeting rooms for videoconferencing.

Comment: Thanks. Then it would be too fancy to call it an advertising company, right?

Comment: That would be misleading to most people, because an ***advertising agency*** or an ***ad agency*** is a company that figures out the marketing and advertising strategy for its clients. For example, McDonald's will hire an ad agency to make a Super Bowl commercial for them and also create Super Bowl signs to put in every McDonald's. The ad agency shoots the TV commercial, and they also design all the related signs, brochures and mailers, so they usually partner with print shops and work closely with them.